# Как отправить cookie

Tags: php, cookie

Пожалуйста, подскажите где ошибся

```
<?
include ('block/db.php');
$login = $_POST['login'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$a = 1;
if ($login == '') {$a = 0; $go = 'index.php';};
if ($pass == '') {$a = 0; $go = 'index.php';};
if ($a == 0){echo'Вы не ввели ЛОГИН или ПАРОЛЬ'; return 0;};
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE mail='$login'",$db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$user_pass = $myrow['pass'];
$idn=$myrow['pass'];
if ($pass <> $user_pass)
{echo 'Вы ввели не правильный ЛОГИН ИЛИ ПАРОЛЬ';return 0; $go = 'index.php';}
else{setcookie("saitName",$idn,time()+864000,"/");};
echo 'Не перезагружайте страницу........';
$go='cs16l.php';
?>

<meta http-equiv="ref" content="2; url=http://sait.ru/<? echo $go ?>">
```

Когда я проверяю на существование куков, он их не находит. Код проверки который я        использую:

```
<? 
if(empty($_COOKIE['saitName']))
{echo'Ошибка';echo'<meta http-equiv="REF" content="3; url=http://sait.ru/index.php">'; return 0;}; $idn = $_COOKIE['saitName']; echo $idn; 
?>
```

Я изменил название домена. И вместо REF - REFRESH

Comment: @kokshe170, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: @kokshe170, ...или делайте для каждой строки кода, не меньше 4х пробелов отступа.

Comment: @eicto, @HA3IK вместо того, что бы взять и отформатировать код, вы берете и пишете бессмысленные сообщения.

Comment: Он не ставится или не отображается в списке кукисов? А то Вы поставили домен "sait.ru" - наверняка он не соответствует вашему реальному, текущему домену.

Comment: Когда я проверяю на существование куков, он их не находит. Код проверки который я использую:

<?
if(empty($_COOKIE['saitName'])){echo'Ошибка';echo'<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="3; url=http://sait.ru/index.php">'; return 0;};
 $idn = $_COOKIE['saitName'];
 echo $idn;
?>

Я изменил название домена.

Comment: @KoVadim и тогда они будут думать что код форматируется автоматически.

Comment: @kokshe170 в 90% случаев у новичков подобное случается, если перед установкой кукисов происходит какой-либо вывод. Иногда лишний перевод строки/пробел может стать причиной. 

@eicto о да. и почему у нас люди такие злые?

Comment: @KoVadim, у меня походу нет пока ещё прав на форматирование вопроса )
@kokshe170, Попробуйте не задавать явно домен (это не обязательный параметр)

Comment: @KoVadim почему злые ? Просто некоторые дают рыбу, а некоторые учат её ловить. вы дали рыбу и теперь в вопросе опять неформатированный код.

Comment: Только что убрал домен.... Но ни чего не изменилось(

Comment: а где вы проверяете в том-же запросе или позже ? зачем вам вообще кука когда есть сессия ?

Comment: Проверяю позже. На другой странице

Comment: @kokshe170, у Вас кукис в браузере не запрещены?)

Comment: Да все включенно. ОТдельно проверил строчку 

    SetCookie('saitName',$idn,time()+3600,"/");

Все работает, куки сохраняет. Как только кидаю строчку в нужный файл ни чего не хочет делать.

Answer (score 1):

Что именно у Вас получается на выходе из ***$myrow['pass']***? Вы проверяли? Если пустое место, то кукис не поставится.

Вы уверены, что код доходит до ***setcookie***? (Поставьте метку, какую-нибудь, что бы проверить).

И попробуйте поставить этот (Нужно 2ва раза обновить, что бы кукис отобразился):

```
setcookie('mycookie','testvalue',time()+36000,'/');
echo $_COOKIE["mycookie"];
```

Comment: Да, $myrow['pass'] я проверял. Вставил код:

setcookie('mycookie','testvalue',time()+36000,'/');
echo $_COOKIE["mycookie"];

Но ни чего..... Куки не выводятся. Обновил раз 10....

Comment: Попробуйте влепить в самом верху вашего кода:  
ini_set("session.use_cookies",1);

Comment: Отдельно проверил строчку

    SetCookie('saitName',$idn,time()+3600,"/");

Все работает, куки сохраняет. Как только кидаю строчку в нужный файл ни чего не хочет делать.

На самый верх поставил строчку

    ini_set("session.use_cookies",1);

Но ни чего не изменилось(

ВОТ САМЫЙ ПОСЛЕДНИЙ ВАРИАНТ:

Comment: <?
$db = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","qwe","qwe") or die("Неверный  ЛОГИН или ПАРОЛЬ к БД");
mysql_select_db("qwe",$db) or die ("Невозможно подключится к БД");
mysql_query('SET names "utf8"');
$login=$_POST['login']; echo $login; echo '</br>';
$pass=$_POST['pass']; echo $pass; echo '</br>';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE mail='$login'",$db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$password=$myrow['pass']; echo $password; echo '</br>';

Comment: if($pass==$password){SetCookie('saitname',$idn,time()+3600,"/");$go='cs16l.php';echo'Не перезагружайте страницу';}else{echo'Вы ввели не правильный логин или пароль'; $go='cs16.php';return 0;};
?>